# How do I Assign Week # from start to end date with week starting on Saturday and ending on Friday?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thank you for your help in advance.

I am trying to write a query that automatically pulls in the week number and date range, so I do not have to manually assign 52 weeks to a specific date range.

The week starts on a Saturday and Ends on a Friday
example of how result should look:

```
Week 1: 2022-01-01 - 2022-01-07
Week 2: 2022-01-08 - 2022-01-14
Week 3: 2022-01-15 - 2022-01-21
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't totally clear what you want but this should at least give you an idea of how this could work. I am using a tally table created with the ctes at the top. Then simply selecting from it at the bottom and doing some date math.

```
declare @StartDate DATE = '20220101';

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )

select *
    , StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, t.N - 1, @StartDate)
    , EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, t.N + 5, @StartDate)
    , WeekNum = (t.N / 7) + 1
    , 'Week ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (t.N / 7) + 1) + ': ' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, t.N - 1, @StartDate)) + ' - ' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, t.N + 5, @StartDate))
from cteTally T
where t.n <= 365
    and t.N % 7 = 1
```

Comment: `TOP (365)` or whatever would be wise

Comment: @Charlieface not sure how using top here would be any better. It is already limited to 365 rows with the where clause.

Comment: But the `WHERE` will still often require reading every one of the 10000 rows, whereas `TOP` will not. Although in testing it appears that the specific case of a `WHERE` against a row-number is optimized into a `TOP` anyway, it's probably better to be explicit. It's not like it costs. See also https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1 for more optimizations. Good answer either way